# Smart phone portrait displays unwanted space underneath squeezed website elements

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design, mobile-website

I've been trying to get the elements of my website to look equally okay on both PC monitors and smart phone displays.

I've tried adding the the meta viewport line within the head section but this doesn't seem to have changed anything:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
```

On my desktop display the site looks like this.

[image]

When I scroll down there is no additional space (which is what I want).

When I view the website on my smart phone, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see the elemts are squeezed into the very top corner and there is a lot of free space below them. I realize there is a difference between portrait and landscape views, but the amount of space seems pretty exaggerated to me.

When I turn the smart phone horizontal it does look okay. However, I would like users to view the site vertically on their smart phones, and for the elements to take up more of the screen.

Here is my html:

```
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-4.0.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/pagestyle.css">

<style type="text/css">


.tuner {position: relative; left:50%; transform:translateX(-50%); margin-top:5%; }
.alttunings {position: absolute; left: 5%; top: 50px; width: 180px;}
.btn-default:hover{background-color:#CCCCCC;border-color:#CCCCCC}

</style>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
</head>
<body>


<div class="tuner">
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="media/standard-tuning.svg">
</object>
<div class="alttunings">

<p>  <button type="button" class="btn btn-block selectedtuning" width=230px>Standard Tuning</button>
  </p>

<p> <button type="button" class="btn btn-block unselectedtuning" width=230px>Open D Tuning</button>
</p>
<p> <button type="button" class="btn btn-block unselectedtuning" width=230px>Drop D Tuning</button>
</p>
<p> <button type="button" class="btn btn-block unselectedtuning" width=230px>Open G Tuning</button>
</p>
</div> 
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script1.js" defer></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>


</html>
```

Here is my main page css:

```
body {
background-color: #C1C1C1;  
width: auto;
}
```

Is there anything else I can try other than using the viewport line that I've already tried?

Comment: *but the amount of space seems pretty exaggerated to me* the pixel count does not change i presume, so it's really okay, if what you want is the content taking the max space possible without scrolling in either support, you could look into responsive divs and images, using `max-width:100%` and `max-height:100%` for example. or @media css. also, please provide at least your html and css in a snippet so we could reproduce yourt issue.

Comment: Hello Neil (that's my name also!). I've added the html and css as requested. I guess the main thing I want is for the image and button to be larger on the phone display, and to consume more of the space, as there isn't going to be a lot else on the page. The svg is also interactive, in that elements can be pressed, and when it's the current size, it's difficult!